# sorting php array by value not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I am getting this result after performing the following on an array.  Shouldn't this be sorting by 'computer_name'?  You will see they are not alpha order.

```
usort($test, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['computer_name'] - $b['computer_name'];
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [computer_id] => 367
            [account_id] => 1
            [computer_name] => EXAMPLE_ONE
            [last_username] => muah
            [timestamp] => 2014-01-01 17:06:04
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [computer_id] => 366
            [account_id] => 1
            [computer_name] => TESTING
            [last_username] => 
            [timestamp] => 2013-12-06 20:02:14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [computer_id] => 365
            [account_id] => 1
            [computer_name] => JOE-SCHMOE
            [last_username] => 
            [timestamp] => 2013-12-06 20:02:03
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [computer_id] => 18
            [account_id] => 1
            [computer_name] => SPORT-ONE
            [last_username] => 
            [timestamp] => 2012-10-16 03:31:22
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [computer_id] => 3
            [account_id] => 1
            [computer_name] => SPORT-TWO
            [last_username] => 
            [timestamp] => 2011-03-03 03:35:46
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that `EXAMPLE_ONE - TESTING`, or `EXAMPLE_ONE - SPORT-ONE` is always equal to 0.

You could try using [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp) here, or the case insensitive version [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

Actually, looking at the documentation for [usort](https://www.php.net/usort), there's an example right in there.  Your example above would be something like

```
usort($test, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['computer_name'], $b['computer_name']);
});
```

Comment: Good find... that did the trick!  I just assumed, but when you explain as you did it makes perfect sense why the results were happening.  Thanks!